# Print out filepath in grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs

I currently have some code that watches for changes in .less files. However I would like to print out there file path, so that at a later date I will be able to add this to a log file.

```
grunt.initConfig({
 watch: {
  less: {
    files: ['vendor/*.less'],
    tasks: ['lessTask'],
    options: {
      spawn: false,
      interrupt: true,
    },
  },
 },
});

grunt.registerTask('lessTask', function(filepath){
   grunt.log.writeln(filepath + ': has changed');
   //Compile less files to CSS
   //Run acceptance tests for UI changes
 });
```

My question is how do I pass over the 'filepath' argument?

Answer (score 1):

With every Grunt task there is a property called `filter` which is intended to use a callback to filter out certain file paths. But it will give you the file path of each file fed to a task:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  less: {
    target: {
      src: 'vendor/*.less',
      dest: 'dist/style.css',
      filter: function(filepath) {
        grunt.log.writeln(filepath + ' fed to less task');
        return true;
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Otherwise if you would like to know which file was changed by the `watch` task; it has a `watch` event:

```
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
  grunt.log.writeln(target + ': ' + filepath + ' has ' + action);
});
```